# `Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “.prisma/client/index-browser”

Tags: node.js, svelte, prisma, vite, sveltekit

I have the following error message in my browser upon using sveltekit and the command  "`npm run preview`":

`Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “.prisma/client/index-browser”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.`

It references a piece of code that was compiled with "`npm run build`" in `localhost:3000/_app/start-b07b1607.js`:

`...s-d1fb5791.js";import".prisma/client/index-browser";let Be="",et="";function ...`

I have tried reproducing this error with using older versions of Prisma, the adaptor and Svelte, switching from pnpm to npm, but nothing helps. I have a MWE repository that comes close to reproducing the error but doesn't actually reproduce it at https://github.com/wvhulle/prisma-sveltekit-bug-report.

How come the Svelte compiler emits “.prisma/client/index-browser” as a module specifier? Is this an error in Prisma, Vite or something else? The dev mode works without problem.

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71258614/error-resolving-module-specifier-vue-relative-module-specifiers-must-start-wi) seems to be related, but is about Vue, not about Svelte.

Thanks!

Comment: > "It references a piece of code that was compiled" < Your code or prisma's?

Comment: @ClemensTolboom I don't recognize my own code in the Svelte compiled (built) file, so I assume it is Prisma's?

Comment: You code exists twice `prisma-client/index-browser.js:1:const prisma = require('.prisma/client/index-browser')` and `prisma-client/scripts/backup-index-browser.js:1:const prisma = require('.prisma/client/index-browser')`

Not sure but ... you can try to change those into `require('./.prisma/client/index-browser')` to check it fixes it? I learned the existance of hidden dirs :-p

Comment: @ClemensTolboom Maybe i confused you with the repository and you thought something is wrong with the repository. It works in the repository, since I couldn't reproduce the issue. So I am not sure what you mean with the comment.

Comment: Your code (not the MWE) has a wrong path which you can edit to see if there's a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the import of a Prisma enum type fixed the issue.

Somewhere in my code I had import an enum type. This seems to be apparently a Prisma problem.

So, remove any `import { Enum } from '@prisma/client';` from your code.

See https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/12504

Comment: I think a better solution is: \
`resolve: {     alias: {       ".prisma/client/index-browser": "./node_modules/.prisma/client/index-browser.js"     }   }` \
from https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/12504#issuecomment-1285883083 \ 
(if that doesnt work, maybe use `@` instead of `.`, `'.prisma/client/index-browser': './node_modules/@prisma/client/index-browser.js',`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy prisma generated files as follows (`package.json`):

```
{
  "prisma:inline": "cp ./node_modules/.prisma/client/*.js ./node_modules/@prisma/client",
  "prisma:generate": "prisma generate && npm run prisma:inline"
}
```